# Angular JS custom validator fails with `ng-invalid-maxlength`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I wrote a custom validator you can find below, it works fine when a value is entered but when something is pre-loaded, on the edit form, it fails with `ng-invalid-maxlength` but `ng-valid-negative`.

When I remove `ba-non-negative` everything works fine. Can someone explain what's wrong?

Usage

```
<input type="text" ba-non-negative ng-model="bookCreateForm.quantity" maxlength="5"/>
```

Non Negative directive

```
'use strict';

angular.module('booksApp')
    .directive('baNonNegative', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('negative', +value >= 0);
                    return +value;
                });

                ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('negative', +value >= 0);
                    return +value;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Edit -

Here's the link to jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/shvz9g28/1/

I am using angular 1.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was returning the value as number, angular has its own validator for maxlength that checks  `viewValue.length <= maxlength;` which always returns false for numbers.

```
  ctrl.$validators.maxlength = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    console.log(viewValue.length );
    return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || viewValue.length <= maxlength;
  };
```

Simple check

```
var a = 1;
a.length <= 5 //false
```

Answer (score 0):

In the formatters validate, if the return value is less than zero then return empty string

```
ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {

    ngModel.$setValidity('negative', +value >= 0);

        if (+value < 0) return '';
              return +value;
    });
```

HTML:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.list_of_items = ['this', 'that', 'the other'];
      $scope.bookCreateForm = {};
      //$scope.bookCreateForm.quantity = -2;
    });

    app.directive('baNonNegative', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('negative', +value >= 0);
                return +value;
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('negative', +value >= 0);

                if (+value < 0) {
                    ngModel.$commitViewValue();
                    return '';
                }
                return (+value) ? +value : '';
            });
        }
    };
});

</script>



<input type="text" ba-non-negative ng-model="bookCreateForm.quantity" maxlength="5"/>
```

Comment: I have added a fiddle for the issue and I think the issue comes on angular 1.3+

Comment: @KarthikEaswaran I've edited this question and added your html.